# Polynomial evaluation at zero.

Tags: polynomials, definition, elementary-functions

Supose we have a polynomial function (what follows is the definition of the book i'm reading) $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ $(0 \leq i \leq n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\wedge a_i \in \mathbb{C})$. My (high school) book defines "numerical evaluation of a number $a$ in $f$ is the image of $a$ by the function $f$" $($i.e $f(a))$ and then proceeds to give some examples without talking about $f(0)$. My question is, we define $f(0)=a_0 \cdot 0^0 =a_0$, even if $0^0$ is undefined?
If so, then $0^0=1$? But if this last one question is true (at least for polynomials) then why in some other subjects $0^0$ is undefined?

The question could be reformulated to: could we avoid making $0^0=1$ (because it is, at least supposedly, undefined), but still mantain $f(0)=a_0$?

I would love to know an answer to this, even if it is very difficult or very easy to understand.

Comment: Check your book. It might have defined $0^0 = 1$ already, to deal with cases like this. Often, it's simply blanket-defined as $x^0 = 1$.

Comment: There are two approaches that I know of: some contend that $0^0=1$ should be standard throughout mathematics and we should say that $x^y$ is discontinuous on $[0,\infty)^2$; others say that in matters of combinatorics and power series we should say that $x^0$ is a placeholder for the constant $1$ function. Essentially, two ways to do the same thing which you don't like. If you want, you may adopt the convention that polynomials must always be written as $a_0+\sum_{j=1}^d a_jx^j$, and make a special case out of the few cases that routinely come up conveniently with the other one.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio More generally, in matters where the exponent is naturally limited to being an integer (and thus where a power expression lends itself more readily to the "repeated multiplication" interpretation). Not just combinatorics and power series, although those are two very prominent examples. Standard ordinal arithmetic does it too, for instance. Peronally, though, I belong to the first camp. Discontinuity all the way.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ is just a way to write $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$, so $0^0=1$ is used here implicitly, but if it bothers you then you can go without summation notation (you will write more text though).

Comment: It is a standard convention to take $0^0$ to be $1$. Without this convention many statements become a little harder to express neatly.

Answer (score 3):

When defining a polynomial the convention is that the "$x^0$" in the constant term is $1$ before you do any evaluation. You need that convention so that formal polynomial multiplication works as expected.

So the $a_0x^0$ term is just $a_0$.